# On the use of frames and functions in Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

My question is, in a flash game I use different frames for levels. And I am confused on how functions work for this. My first frame works fine but I need help with using functions on other frames and keeping functions specific to one frame. Any help is appreciated, just a quick simple explanation

Answer (score 1):

You cannot associate a function with a specific frame.

When you execute code on a frame, what actually happens is the `MovieClip` containing that frame will call a function called `addFrameScript()`, passing to it a representation of the code you write on the frame.

This means:

- Until you visit a frame that defines a function, you cannot call said function.
- Once you have visited a frame that defines a function, that function is attached to the parent MovieClip, and you are able to call the function at any point in the timeline that is earlier or later.
- If you try to define a new function with the same name on a different frame, you will get a `1021: Duplicate function definition` error.

Instead of making a new function for every frame or *level*, you should make a single function that is able to handle different information that is representative of a level, e.g.

```
function loadLevel(level:int):void
{
    // Do stuff with the value of level.
    // For example, this function might look at a data source that maps
    // the level numbers to some level data representing tile placement.
}
```

This could be defined on the first frame, then on each subsequent frame:

```
loadLevel(1); // Frame 2
loadLevel(2); // Frame 3
// ...etc
```

All of this of course is not ideal and could be done better avoiding the timeline and instead using to OOP paradigm that AS3 provides.

Answer (score 0):

I have found using multiple levels within the same scene causes no end to headaches for me.
I'm no expert & i'm sure its possible to do so in many cases and I have seen some great games created using 1 frame 1 scene & all code in an external .as.

However I find it much easier myself to just use 1 frame per level and put each level in a different Scene.